# remove text quotations using sql

Tags: sql

I am getting data from odbc connection using SQL , the problem I have is that all the text format data still have " " , is there anything in SQL I can add to remove these please. example "John" would like it to be just John

Comment: That's not an SQL or ODBC issue, must be something that happens in the layer above.

Comment: Look for functions like `REPLACE` or `TRIM` for your particular DBMS.